# cannot insert into the database in ActiveRecord Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii2

I don't know what's wrong but I cannot insert into the database.

this is what I got in the model.

warranty.php

```
<?php

    namespace app\models;

    use Yii;
    use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
    use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
    use yii\db\Expression;
    use yii\helpers\VarDumper;
    /**
     * This is the model class for table "warrantytwo".
     *
     * @property integer $id
     * @property string $item_no
     * @property string $warranty_date
     * @property string $date
     * @property integer $created_by
     * @property string $tstamp
     */
    class Warrantytwo extends ActiveRecord
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public static function tableName()
        {
            return 'warrantytwo';
        }

        public function behaviors()
        {
            return [
                [
                    'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
                    'createdAtAttribute' => 'tstamp',
                    'updatedAtAttribute' => false,
                    'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
                ],
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                [['item_no', 'warranty_date'], 'required'],

                [['warranty_date', 'date'], 'string'],

                ['created_by', 'default', 'value' => 'none'],

                [['created_by'], 'integer'],

                [['warranty_date', 'date','tstamp'], 'safe'],

                [['item_no'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
            ];
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function attributeLabels()
        {
            return [
                'id' => 'ID',
                'item_no' => 'Item No.',
                'warranty_date' => 'Warranty Date',
                'date' => 'Date',
                'created_by' => 'Created By',
                'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
            ];
        }

        public function addWarrantytwo()
        {
            if ($this->validate()) {
                $Warrantytwo = new Warrantytwo();
                $Warrantytwo->item_no = $this->item_no;
                $Warrantytwo->warranty_date = $this->warranty_date;
                $Warrantytwo->created_by = 'admin1';
                $Warrantytwo->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                //$Warrantytwo->touch('tstamp');

                if ($Warrantytwo->save()) 
                {
                    return $Warrantytwo;
                }else {
                    VarDumper::dump($Warrantytwo->getErrors());
                }
            }

            //return null;
        }
    }
```

controller.php

```
public function actionWarranty()
    {
        //$model= new WarrantyDate();
        $model= new Warrantytwo();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->addWarrantytwo()) {
            return $this->redirect(['warranty']);
        } 
        else {
        return $this->render('warranty', [
            'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

and in my views/form

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
      'id' => 'new-warranty-form',
      //'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'], //for yii\ActiveForm
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL, //for krajee\ActiveForm
        'formConfig' => ['labelSpan' => 4, 'deviceSize' => ActiveForm::SIZE_SMALL]  ]); ?>
                <div class="form-horizontal">

  <?= $form->field($model, 'item_no', 
        ['addon' => ['append' => ['content'=> '<a href="#w" onClick="sample()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>']]    ]); ?>                          

    <?= $form->field($model, 'warranty_date')-> widget(DatePicker::classname(),
    [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Date Claimed'],
    'pluginOptions' => [ 'autoclose'=>true ]
                ]); ?>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-md-9">

     <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'warranty-button']) ?>

  <?= Html::resetButton('Reset', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']); ?>
     </div>

     <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

It doesn't give any errors but when I check it on the database, nothing added. I hope anyone can help me. Thank you. I'm new to YII2 so I still don't get it.

Comment: Can you tell me value of `warranty_date` post to action?

Comment: @gamitg i the value is a date, I think. I used a kartik datepicker widget. and I also changed my data type in mysql to `text` instead of `date` for ensuring that the date can be added up in the dbase.

Comment: You can try to save data using `$Warrantytwo->save(false)`. It means without validation save data for find the issue.

Comment: in your Model `warrantyTwo.php` function `addWarrantytwo()`, `print_r($warrantytwo); exit(0);` above the save line and you will see the possible errors

Comment: I tried using both what you had suggested about print_r and save(false) but still nothing. even the error. :(
@ankitraturi

Comment: I have this same kind of problem in adding up a user. I thought it was just in user, because it was a bit complicated to do. but i think there is wrong with my namespace? i think not. is there something I didn't declared?
@gamitg

Comment: Is the form validated successfully? Double check this.

Comment: @ankitraturi I don't know. on the first trial, I saw some error and the POST do have a value but after some tweaking in the code, i do not get any error but i still have my form filled up with the details I have inputted so I guess, it is not validated successfully.  but why? I can't cracked up my brain anymore. haha. XD

Comment: In case of addWarrantytwo() succeeds the output of VarDumper or print_r won't be visible because of the redirect. Usually, in such situations, I just insert an `exit;` after such commands.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to determine in what situations the problem occurs the test in this way. (Sometimes it creates a bit of confusion because validate () returns always something)

```
    public function addWarrantytwo()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $Warrantytwo = new Warrantytwo();
            $Warrantytwo->item_no = $this->item_no;
            $Warrantytwo->warranty_date = $this->warranty_date;
            $Warrantytwo->created_by = 'admin1';
            $Warrantytwo->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            //$Warrantytwo->touch('tstamp');

            if ($Warrantytwo->save(false))   // try save without validation 
            {
                return $Warrantytwo;
            }else {
                VarDumper::dump($Warrantytwo->getErrors());
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
            VarDumper::dump($this->validate());  // check for the correct flow
            exit;
        }

        //return null;
    }
```

Comment: hello, sir. I tried your answer, after the form submit, I only get a "false" word. where do you think was the error?  thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: Then the validate return false . for  find the erro rtry commenting selectively your rules. This will help you identify the cause of the validation error. ` [['warranty_date', 'date'], 'string'],`  date string is strange.

Comment: I think I know where the error is. it's the data type of the created_by. But I will vote up your asnwer because I find it helpful in finding where the error happened. thank you!

Comment: thank if you vote up. I hope this answer it is helpful to allow you to find the error.

Comment: yes. very helpful. :) in fact, I will use it for some debugging purposes. so that I will know where is the error happened, in the validation rule that didn't return any errors or in saving the data, thanks! :D